# Assignments to variables get printed on stdout in zsh script

Tags: shell, zsh

This is an example script that reproduces the issue:

*example.zsh*

```
zmodules=(foo bar/baz)

local zmodule
for zmodule (${zmodules}); do
  local zurl zname
  zname=${zmodule##*/}
  case ${#zmodule//[^\/]/} in
    0) zurl="https://github.com/foo/${zmodule}" ;;
    1) zurl="https://github.com/${zmodule}" ;;
  esac
  print "${zurl} ${zname}"
done
```

The current result of running the script:

```
$ source ./example.zsh 2>/dev/null
zmodule=bar/baz
zurl=https://github.com/bar/baz
zname=baz
https://github.com/foo/foo foo
zurl=https://github.com/foo/foo
zname=foo
https://github.com/bar/baz baz
```

Expected result:

```
$ source ./example.zsh 2>/dev/null
https://github.com/foo/foo foo
https://github.com/bar/baz baz
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**: I guess I got it: `local` only works inside functions. But why is it printing the assignments anyway when I declare the variables local?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you are executing `local` repeatedly in the `for` loop. From `man zshbuiltins`:

> `local`
>
> Same as `typeset`, except ...
>
> `typeset`
>
> Set or display attributes and values for shell parameters.

Consequently, executing `local var` (**without** any assignment) will cause `zsh` to display attributes and values of that variable *if it already exists*. See this snippet demonstrating that behavior:

```
$ local var
$ var=10
$ local var
var=10
$ local var=15
$ local var2=20 var
var=15
```

---

***Side note**: you may be asking why both assignments are being printed whereas in my example, the first `local` doesn't print anything. That is because you are using `source` to run the script so the variables are **already** set from your previous attempts.*

Answer (score 2):

In zshell, the `local`/`typeset` commands display the value of any variable which is already defined.  Your `local` definition command is executed multiple times, and the latter ones print the value of the variables instead of making them local as you wanted.  You can disable this feature with the `TYPESET_SILENT` shell options.

> setopt TYPESET_SILENT